# Accessing the individual columns of list of matrices in Python

Tags: python

Suppose I have a array of matrices like the following. I want to access the every first element of the each matrix and give it to a variable a and every second element of each matrix to variable b and it goes on c,d,e... I want to plot a, b, c... individually to see the variance and that is why I need to extract it to separate variables.

```
[matrix([[-0.92041113],
                [ 1.08098058],
                [ 0.14296712],
                [ 0.68220346],
                [-2.06009246],
                [ 2.67064141],
                [ 0.02112063],
                [-3.10444805],
                [ 2.65878653],
                [-2.07589813],
                [-2.06215593],
                [ 0.85664044],
                [-3.74867982]]), 
    matrix([[-0.92040691],
                [ 1.08097285],
                [ 0.14295496],
                [ 0.68220521],
                [-2.06007836],
                [ 2.67064582],
                [ 0.02111738],
                [-3.10443457],
                [ 2.65875017],
                [-2.07586394],
                [-2.06215174],
                [ 0.85664019],
                [-3.74867324]]), 
    matrix([[-0.92040268],
                [ 1.08096513],
                [ 0.1429428 ],
                [ 0.68220696],
                [-2.06006425],
                [ 2.67065023],
                [ 0.02111412],
                [-3.1044211 ],
                [ 2.65871382],
                [-2.07582975],
                [-2.06214755],
                [ 0.85663994],
                [-3.74866666]]), 
    matrix([[-0.92039846],
                [ 1.08095741],
                [ 0.14293065],
                [ 0.68220871],
                [-2.06005015],
                [ 2.67065464],
                [ 0.02111087],
                [-3.10440762],
                [ 2.65867747],
                [-2.07579557],
                [-2.06214336],
                [ 0.8566397 ],
                [-3.74866008]])]
```

The following is my trying,

```
[beta_array[i][0] for i in range(0,3)]
```

But the output I am getting is like as follows,

```
[matrix([[-0.92041113]]),
 matrix([[-0.92040691]]),
 matrix([[-0.92040268]]),
 matrix([[-0.92039846]])]
```

i am not able to plot anything with this output. My ideal output would be (-0.92041113,-0.92040691,-0.92040268,-0.92039846) in variable a and it goes one.   If it is a proper variable of values, I can easily plot it. Can anybody help me in doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following code:

```
[float(beta_array[i][0]) for i in range(0,3)]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is:

```
[beta_array[i][0][0] for i in range(0,3)]
```

Though I'm not sure what that `matrix()` call you have in there does. What framework are you using for this?

Comment: This one gives me a output like this [matrix([[-0.92041113]]), matrix([[-0.92040691]]), matrix([[-0.92040268]])], which I dont want.

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be to *not* make individual entries matrices within the larger matrix (instead just leave it as a big list), and then do

```
a = matrix[:,0]
b = matrix[:,1]
```

etc.

Comment: I am getting the following error,

TypeError: list indices must be integers, not tuple

Answer (score 0):

Ask for index `0, 0`, not for index `0`:

```
>>> [beta_array[i][0, 0] for i in range(0,3)]
[-0.92041112999999997, -0.92040690999999997, -0.92040268000000003]
```

Or better:

```
>>> [beta[0, 0] for beta in beta_array]
[-0.92041112999999997, -0.92040690999999997, -0.92040268000000003, -0.92039846000000003]
```

(No idea why you use `range(0, 3)` when you want to cover all four matrices.)